# How we can use Fluentd in AKS or Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, fluentd, azure-aks

Can someone guide me how we can have container logs with the help of EFK(Elasticsearch,Fluentd,Kibana) for AKS or Openshift

My requirement is to download logs of container with retain period to check is container had an issue so that I can store it and use it for RCA or something like that. because if container gets restarted it will vanish all the previous logs

• Downloading log file ? Tail mode ? just last 100 lines ?

• Central logging with ELK/EFK

Regards,

SAMURAI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about either of those except AKS is already using containerd. OpenShift might be using Docker or CRIO depending on version and config, but all of those are well documented in the Fluentd docs.

tl;dr you do it by doing it, there is no special magic.